# Scrolling WebBrowser Control Fails

Tags: visual-studio, webbrowser-control, vb.net-2010

I have a web browser control in a VS 2010 winforms application. When loading long web pages that are longer than the control's window the document will not scroll completely when you use the scroll bar. The scroll bar goes to the bottom, but there is more document to be viewed. It will scroll completely when you use the mouse wheel. I've tried two different methods to load the document and both react the same way when it comes to scrolling. I've also tried this on two different computers. Even after the scrool bar goes to the bottom, without reloading the document, you can switch to the wheel and view the rest of the document.

I have two web browser controls in this application. The other one with the same document does not behave this way. The one that works as expected is in a SplitContainter and the one that does not is in a TableLayout control.

Has any one else experienced this? is there away I can change this behavior?

Greg

```
            'one
            Dim fileContents As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(tvwDocuments.SelectedNode.Name)
            webDoc.DocumentText = fileContents
            webDoc.Refresh()

            'two
            webDoc.Navigate("about:blank")
            webDoc.Document.OpenNew(False)
            Dim fileContents As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(tvwDocuments.SelectedNode.Name)
            webDoc.Document.Write(fileContents)
            webDoc.Refresh()
```

Comment: WebBrowser can be buggy at times. Do you have the latest version of IE?

Comment: IE 9 and can't change because of work